# Diverting incoming array item from one variable to another in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

It's a bit of a contrived example below, but it illustrates my problem well. On click, 'a' gets passed a couple of items and I want to make sure the last one gets diverted to 'b' automatically instead of 'a' as part of the same click handler. After the function ran, I would like to see the following state rendered: a = ['Adam', 'Brett'] and b = ["Donald", "Eric", "Fred", "Cody"]

Creating a copy to use the pop method as per below doesn't work as the new state for 'a' hasn't been reflected yet. Any hints welcome.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Test() {
  const [a, SetA] = useState([]);
  const [b, SetB] = useState(["Donald", "Eric", "Fred"]);

  function click() {
    SetA((prev) => [...prev, "Adam", "Brett", "Cody"]);
    const aCopy = [...a];
    const mover = aCopy.pop();
    SetA((prev) => [...prev, aCopy]);
    SetB((prev) => [...prev, mover]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Group A: {a}</div>
      <div>Group B: {b}</div>
      <button onClick={click}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
> pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
> method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
> guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
> be batched for performance gains.

TLDR; you can't access state right after setState.

What you can do instead is to create 2 new arrays with the values you wanted, and setState after, something like this:

```
  function click() {
    const newA = [...a, "Adam", "Brett", "Cody"];
    const newB = newA.slice(0, newA.length - 1);
    SetA(newA);
    SetB(newB);
  }
```